# What type of switch is this?

Tags: electrical, switch, appliances

I am trying to replace the switch in my space heater, but am unsure what type it is to do a search for it. It has three terminals one one side and 2 on the other.

This part is from a Duraflame heater (Model: [DFH-NH-1-T](http://www.twinstarhome.com/duraflame/products/DFH-NH-3-T/index.html)).

[image: Switch]

[image: Switch]

Comment: CQC brand.  Confusing markings.  One side shows 250VAC, the other 125VAC, but at least you know it's 15A rating is clear.

Comment: It looks a lot like a switch you would find in a box fan. The main difference being that box fans typically use push-in connections instead of blade connections.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this site: http://www.czjinhe.com/english/content/product5.htm

Which show some information about your switch and might sell it. I used this query with google: zhongling pa66 xk-2 switch

Comment: PA66 identifies that the switch is made of polyamide (nylon) 6-6, so probably isn't necessary to uniquely identify the part.

Comment: @zersped I e-mailed the company and they responded with the following: `"Dear sir:This switch is our patented products, but this switch is a copy one. www.czjinhe.com If you buy heater which use our switch, it will not out of order. I think you could ask the the heater service department to change one for free. Thanks and Best regards!"`

Comment: I created a ticket to [Twinstar](https://www.tsicustomerservice.com) which is the company that makes the Duraflame heater (Model: DFH-NH-1-T), but they responded with the following: `"Thanks for the inquiry sorry to say we don't have any parts for this units/ thanks/"`